# Add FBA Roles to SharePoint 2013 site and assign permissions programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, role-provider

I have a problem with adding a FBA role to a sharepoint 2013 site programmatically. I tried `web.ensureuser` method and `web.Siteusers.Add()` methods and none of them works for me.

```
SPUser spUser = spWeb.EnsureUser("c:0-.f|ie-fbarolesprovider|groupName");
```

Thanks

shharepoint developer

Answer (score 1):

You can see below link to add fba users

[http://suryapulipati.blogspot.in/2012/07/sharepoint-2010-fba-add-fba-users-to.html]

And for assigning the permissions to the user see the below code:

```
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment("dom\\user", "user@dom", "user", "some notes");
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
if (!myList.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    myList.BreakRoleInheritance(true); // Ensure we don't inherit permissions from parent
} 
myList.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
myList.Update();
```